# How to replace word "magic"?

Tags: sihr

Salam. Was reading articles on the internet, found that word "magic" is often used to say when something works, but is not clear how,
for example:

- How that program/engine/paste here works?
- I do not know, it's "magic".

Could you please suggest good replacement word/expression so as not to use "it's magic".

Comment: how this is connected with Islam ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to use the word "magic" for something you don't understand how it works. Nothing wrong with it.

In computer programs, "magic" or "magic number" is used to describe something which works but is difficult to understand or a number which is present in the logic but nothing describes why is it there.

Some good replacements would be:

- Trick
- Hack
- Workaround

Comment: "Trick" is nicest, IMHO.

Comment: If your question has been answered please mark it as accepted to remove it from pool of unanswered questions

Comment: Sorry, Mustaghees, accepted.